# Is it possible to get the area between $y^2 = 3x$ and $y = x^3$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a Grade 12 student taking Calculus. Our lesson for tomorrow is about area between curves. Our teacher gave this question for us to ponder about and do advanced study. Can someone explain this and why or why not you can get the area between the given curves?

Is it possible to get the area between $y^2 = 3x$ and $y = x^3$?

Using:
A. Horizontal Strips or B. Vertical Strips

Why or why not?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you drawn a graph? I guess your teacher will tell you all about it.

Comment: Only you have to ponder about whether it's possible or not. You wouldn't benefit if others would spoon-feed you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the area using both. If you sketch the graph of the two curves, the upper function and also the left function is $y^2=3x$, and the lower function and the right function is $y=x^3$. The point of intersection of the two curves are at $(0, 0)$ and $(\sqrt[5]3, 3^{\frac{3}{5}})$. By now, you should know how to get the intersection between two curves.

For A. Horizontal Strips

$A=\int_c^d $ (right function) $-$ (left function) $dy$

Use $y=0$ and $y=3^{\frac{3}{5}}$

$A=\int_0^{3^{\frac{3}{5}}}(\sqrt[3]{y}-\frac{y^2}{3})dy$

$A=\left[\frac{3y\sqrt[3]{y}}{4}-\frac{y^3}{9} \right]^{3^{\frac{3}{5}}}_{0}$

$A=\frac{5}{4\sqrt[5]3}$ square units

For B. Vertical Strips

$A=\int_a^b $ (upper function) $-$ (lower function) $dx$

Use $x=0$ and $x=\sqrt[5]3$.

$A=\int_0^\sqrt[5]3(\sqrt{3x}-x^3)dx$

$A=\left[\frac{2x\sqrt{3x}}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4} \right]^{\sqrt[5]3}_{0}$

$A=\frac{5}{4\sqrt[5]3}$ square units

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Imagine the area you are trying to define as a four bounded shape:
[image: graph of functions]

What we have is the red function ($y^2=3x$ or simplified to $y=\sqrt{3x}$) on top and the blue ($y=x^3$) below. Now we know that the integral of a function represents the area between the function and the axis, so if we take the integral of the red and minus the integral of the blue we are left with the area between them. The other thing that is left to do is find the bounds for $x$. One is obviously $0$ and the other is the solution to:
$$\sqrt{3x}=x^3$$ Which will come out as $x=\sqrt[5]{3}$ Now bringing it all together will yield:
$$\text{Area}=\int\limits_0^{\sqrt[5]{3}}\left(\sqrt{3x}-x^3\right)\,dx$$

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Good answer (+1) but you shouldn't answer on poor quality homework question. The question shows no effort done.